# Added UITableViewCell GestureRecognizer Delegate Not Working

Tags: ios, uitableview, protocols, uigesturerecognizer, custom-cell

**Current Progress**

I have a table where a swipe gesture should bring up a new ViewController. It actually works and can call the segue and load the new VC (all code below, should be helpful to anyone just wanting to add a gesture).

**Problem**

But I want to pass the new ViewController the swiped-cell's index value, and I've been unable to do this or replicate the methods explained in guides I've found.

My table use a custom cell class, which is where the gesture is added. The gesture is added, I've tested it, and it does use the delegate to trigger a function in the main VC and trigger the segue.

The error definitely seems to be happening right at the start, when I try to capture the initial sender and pass it through the delegate.

**Code**

Here's my custom cell's code:

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet var nameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var descLabel: UILabel!

var delegate: mainViewDelegate!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code

    //Create 'swipeLeft' variable, provide action (swipedLeft) and add to cell
    let swipeLeft: UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "swipedLeft")
    swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left
    self.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)

}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

func swipedLeft (sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    println("swipe detected, cell function run")
    if(self.delegate != nil){
        self.delegate.cellSwipedLeft(sender)
    }
}   
}
```

The protocol:

```
protocol mainViewDelegate {
    func cellSwipedLeft (UISwipeGestureRecognizer)
}
```

Main ViewController header:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, mainViewDelegate {
```

And I also added the needed delegate line in the main VC's cellForRowAtIndexPath function:

```
func tableView... 
...  (edited out to save space)
cell.delegate = self
}
```

The main VC function:

```
func cellSwipedLeft (sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    println("cellSwipedLeft main VC func ran")
    performSegueWithIdentifier("modalTo_HomeTaskAction", sender: nil)
}
```

Now all this works if I'm not passing anything in the parameters, but when I add the UISwipeGestureRecognizer, it fails with a Thread 1: signal SIGABRT error. My goal is to pass the gesture successfully, then I'll add the below code to get the index and use prepareForSegue to pass it to my VC:

```
let gesture = sender as! UISwipeGestureRecognizer
let cell = gesture.view! as! CustomTableViewCell_F2
let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)
```

So the big question is, why does passing the UISwipeGestureRecognizer get me an error that start like this:

```
2015-08-21 03:23:39.566 AppName[10170:945334] -[AppName.CustomTableViewCell swipedLeft]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb149766560
2015-08-21 03:23:39.619 AppName[10170:945334] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-   [AppName.CustomTableViewCell swipedLeft]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb149766560'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                          0x0000000106dfcc65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000108ba9bb7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dave, here's an easier way to do this, this is without protocols and instead we use blocks. in your custom UITableViewCell, we do this:

**THE SETUP:**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class EXTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var descLabel: UILabel!
    var doWork: (() -> Void)?
    func swipedLeft (sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
        if let callback = self.doWork {
            println("swipe detected, cell function run")
            callback ()
        }
    }
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        let swipeLeft: UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "swipedLeft")
        swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left
        self.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)
    }
    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }
}
```

Custom ViewController:

```
import UIKit

class DetailViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return  0 //replace with the correct info
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 4 //replace with the correct info
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FFViewCell
          cell.doWork = {
              () -> Void in
              self.doStuff(indexPath.row)
        }
          cell.labelMessage.text = items[indexPath.row] as String
          return cell
      }
      func doStuff(integer: NSInteger) {
          println("i got here \(integer)")
      }
}
```

**How this works:**

You see, we are declaring a block property that lets us pass an empty "function" call (PER SE) to any "EXTableViewCell" that you create in your UIViewController.

So, in the custom UITableViewCell, we declare a void block property:

```
var doWork: (() -> Void)?
```

We attach a touch handler to the cell:

```
func swipedLeft (sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
        if let callback = self.doWork {
            println("swipe detected, cell function run")
            callback ()
        }
    }
```

We then call to this handler inside or main UIViewController and set this property when we configure our table view Cells:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! EXTableViewCell
        cell.doWork = {
            () -> Void in
            self.doStuff()
        }
        return cell
    }
```

Specifically:

```
cell.doWork = {
            () -> Void in
            self.doStuff()
        }
```

We obviously then set up the "doStuff" function to do what we want it to do in our UIViewController:

```
func doStuff() {
        println("i got here")
    }
```

No protocols, no mess, no screwing around with making delegation happen, all block based features. I've not tested this code with an actual UIViewController, however, this does work flawlessly in Objective-C and before posting this code, I made sure that it compiles.

As a quick note to the awesomeness of blocks, nearly everything that seems super complex with delegation and protocols can be accomplished with blocks, the tough part is getting use to using blocks and understanding their versatility. Probably the most enjoyable part is the fact that you can use "block properties" just like a normal property but with the added benefit of attaching a handler event to the object who owns the block property. Anyway, one more thing you may need to do is this, but this is simple:

You may need to start your custom table view cell like so, making it a delegate of UIGestureRecognizer like so:

```
class EXTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
```

and you may need to declare your gesture recognizer in the custom table view cell class so it looks something like this:

```
swipeLeft.delegate = self
swipeLeft.cancelsTouchesInView = false
```

Also, if you have trouble making this happen, then let me know, I'll see if I can't just get a full implementation going for it.

Working example, tested and ready to go:

Custom tableViewCell:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class FFViewCell: UITableViewCell, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    var labelMessage = UILabel()

    var doWork: (() -> Void)?

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        let swipeLeft: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "this")

        swipeLeft.delegate = self
        swipeLeft.cancelsTouchesInView = false

        self.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)

        labelMessage.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        contentView.addSubview(labelMessage)
        var viewsDict =  ["labelMessage" : labelMessage]

        contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[labelMessage]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))
        contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-20-[labelMessage]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))

    }
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    func this () {
        if let callback = self.doWork {
            println("swipe detected, cell function run")
            callback ()
        }
    }

}
```

AppDelegate:

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var rootViewController: UINavigationController?
    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

        rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ViewController())
        if let window = window {
            window.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

            window.rootViewController = rootViewController

            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
        return true
    }
    func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }


}
```

ViewController:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var tableView : UITableView?
    var items = ["asdf","asdf","asdf","asdf","asdf"]

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    }
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView = UITableView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 414, 736), style: UITableViewStyle.Plain)
        tableView!.delegate = self
        tableView!.dataSource = self
        tableView!.registerClass(FFViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        self.view .addSubview(tableView!)
    }
    override func loadView() {
        var stuf = UIView()
        stuf.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 414, 736)
        stuf.backgroundColor = UIColor .redColor()
        self.view = stuf
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count;
    }
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(tableView:UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath)->CGFloat
    {
        return 44
    }   
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FFViewCell
        cell.doWork = {
            () -> Void in
            self.doStuff()
        }
        cell.labelMessage.text = items[indexPath.row] as String
        return cell
    }
    func doStuff() {
        println("i got here")
    }
}
```

Here's the "swipe gesture" code, Dave:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class FFViewCell: UITableViewCell, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    var labelMessage = UILabel()

    var doWork: (() -> Void)?

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        let swipeLeft: UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "this")
        swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left
        swipeLeft.delegate = self
        swipeLeft.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        self.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)

        labelMessage.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        contentView.addSubview(labelMessage)
        var viewsDict =  ["labelMessage" : labelMessage]

        contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[labelMessage]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))
        contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-20-[labelMessage]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))

    }
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    func this () {
        if let callback = self.doWork {
            println("swipe detected, cell function run")
            callback ()
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Larcerax, thank you. This block thing is completely new to me. What does void mean? Also, do I now get the index path by just referencing the 'cell' variable? I will definitely try this but want to be more awake for it. It's almost 6am here and I've been working on this all night, so in about 8-10 hours I'll let you know if it worked. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, so you can reference the cell the same way you are doing, more than likely, and "void" just means there's no return value, it's just funciton that does work and that's it

Comment: I'll probably have a solution fleshed out entirely over the next 2 hours, so when you are up and awake recheck the answer

Comment: Actually, Dave, I got it done, it's working, I'll add the details.

Comment: It didn't work! What blows me away is that I deleted all my protocol related code, triple checked that I did everything you outlined, and the error is the same. Printed in the console is the: 'AppName.CustomTableViewCell swipedLeft]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa893cc1a50'       And as a reminder, this is very odd because the gesture did work with the protocol, but only when I removed the UISwipeGestureRecognizer from the parameter of the function being delegated. Now as that delegation is gone and your code is in and it gets the same error? This is baffling

Comment: you have to do this exactly, don't change this: func this () {
        if let callback = self.doWork {
            println("swipe detected, cell function run")
            callback ()
        }

Comment: DO NOT pass the "Sender" to these functions, don't do it, just leave them be

Comment: That's the crazy thing! I didn't change them, I pasted them in and let them be. So as far as I can understand, nothing is being passed to them.

Comment: AND, I made this with a "tap gesture", you'll want to change it to "swipe gesture", but just don't pass "sender" or anything to the functions you are calling, it's not necessary, and i had this problem you did until I removed the sender and just kept the functions as "func this ()" and "func doStuff()"

Comment: wow, that's lame, it's working for me, let me upload the project for you, you can see it

Comment: I appreciate it but not sure that'll help. I've looked at the example you made, and in all the relevant places, mine looks the same. I followed every step. It's like there is something wrong with the gesture recognizer because it still fails so early, but the gesture works fine when I remove my old protocol code and your block code. Which makes me think there's some error happening when the two views try to talk in any way.

Comment: Dave, also, here's the visual output you want to see, this will verify that the touches are going to both the UIViewController and the UITableViewCell: YOU SHOULD SEE THIS IN THE DEBUGGER:          "swipe detected, cell function run
i got here"

Comment: That's strange, this was such a simple solution, but if you do get a chance to look at the folder I upload, it's super simplified, perhaps its a problem with a "swipe gesture" or something, all I know is that it detects touches very easily

Comment: Nevermind, you were right, I was still passing the gesture. I'm an idiot and didn't see it!! It works!!!!! You rock, thank you, thank you!

Comment: lol, that's awesome, i just tried it with the Swipe,, and it works, too, this solution will blow your mind for months and months to come, not too many people know how to use blocks this way, and this will make your life soooo much easier to deal with, you have no idea! I'm glad it works!

Comment: Dave, I'm also going to add up there, the swipegesture code, just in case

Comment: Although, if I can't pass the gesture in the UITableViewCell, how am I going to get my index? Can I modify the doStuff function in the cellForRowAtIndexPath to send the function the cellForRowAtIndexPath cell?

Comment: yep, you can add as much as you want, the thing is, each of the customcells is able to retain it's value per where it was located, I'm not sure really why this is even possible, but it does, that's why when I customize UITableVIewCells, you can load those cells up with all sorts of crap and be just fine, from what i've tested. There could be something more to this, but if there is, I've not found it, the declaration of the property is enough for this method to maintain itself solid no matter what you pass to the cell

Comment: AND you are passing it to the cell, that's why I put a "println" in the custom cell, you'll see that the debugger shows the println for both the UIViewController function and the customCell function, so it's hitting both functions in 1, that's how this works

Comment: One more thing, this also works the same way for UICollectionViews, so you don't need to touch the crappy delegate methods there, for the most part, when you deal with touches on collection views, this works in so many different areas that the crappy delegation stuff sort of goes in the trash can, you'll still need to use delegation, obviously, but the passing of this or than from subclasses is simplified using this method

Comment: I'm really struggling with this one, if you could do me the last favor of showing me what code I can insert in the cellForRowAtIndexPath to save the cell in a way that is accessible outside of the function, I'd be thrilled. I can't really just call the tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath's and access it's return cell. How do I make its most recent index value save to a variable that other functions can use? Or do I somehow get the index and pass it in the UITableViewCell? Without this detail, I'm back to where I started with protocols, a working empty function being passed.

Comment: Oh I see, so the cell block thing we did is just 1 attribute of that cell, if you can add as many as you like. The cell index still stays the same as if we didn't do what we just did, the point is this, in that return function, you don't have to leave the function blank, this one I mean " func doStuff() {" you can pass variables to this function like you normally would. I don't know much about Swift, but here's an example " func doStuff(integer: NSInteger, string: String) {" etc, etc.

Comment: this means you can pass the information from the Cell and index row to the function, and then you van do stuff with the function. I do this in Objective C so that I can force the information from the Cell into a ViewConrioller when the user touches the cell, the information I pass is from block to the " func doStuff() " function, but instead of leaving this funciton blank, it's like I showed you above, one sec.

Comment: Boom, magic. Alright, this works. You've saved me from going insane, lol. Why do you choose to help people with such frustrating problems? I'm just curious.

Comment: I've only been programming IOS for 6 months, and I know a lot, but I could know more, I learn very very fast, but it's this kind of stuff that forces me to learn even more

Comment: but don't be fooled by this, I come from a programming background, it's not going to be this easy for everyone

Comment: Well, that's impressive. lol. Well it's cool that there's people out there like you. I have tried answering questions where I can but I'm no one near as helpful. Thanks again.